# Where to post ops support questions for GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

stackoverflow Mod just closed down an ops support request as non-programming. Fair from the stackoverflow perspective.

It's just that Google has dumped support for GAE  on stackoverflow.
https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java
Struck me as odd, but I thought they'd be on the same page with stackoverflow for it. Apparently not.

So where does the (disenchanted!) user of GAE turn for ops support?!

Comment: You're free to post any programming/code related question here on SO. Your previous one got closed because it was only "valid" for a certain amount of time. Whenever AppEngine would be up and running again, your question would become of no value for future visitors of SO: such questions simply do not belong on SO. Note that in the link you posted, they're are talking about moving Q&A's regarding Python and Java questions to SO (which belong on SO), not posting questions if certain services are down or not (which don't belong on SO).

Comment: Totally understood. Google's bad in my perspective to not coordinate with stackoverflow, everybody's left high and dry with that stupid decision. I'll leave you guys alone with this, will see if I can ping Google dev advocates...

Comment: I understand your sentiment, and hope you can get through to the AppEngine people!

Answer (score 3):

I think you've misinterpreted the announcement email. It indicated that Stack Overflow would be the official channel for *development questions* (which are an excellent fit for the SO model). And, while the runtime-specific groups were closed, the general forum remains open:

> The 
>   google-appengine http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine group 
>   will remain open for general discussions and announcements that are better 
>   suited for the groups format.